# My question has been deleted. It was new and unresolved. Why?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Are complex javascript URLs not supported when following links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039752/are-complex-javascript-urls-not-supported-when-following-links)

I posted a question here on meta asking why my question had been closed. That meta question was heavily downvoted. Is it off topic on meta to ask advice on how to form a good question, how to improve? Now my original question has been deleted, even though I tried my best to accommodate all the suggestions, and revised the original question.

The original issue wasn't resolved. I found out on my own that Firefox behavior had changed over time causing the original issue, but that doesn't give me the workaround I requested in the original post. I would like to have some explanation on why my question was deleted outright. If my original question can be improved further, please advise. If someone can edit it for me, to be more appropriate, I would be grateful.

For those downvoting and reporting, has SO become toxic or highly toxic or what?
Is there a squash the noob practice going on that I haven't heard about?

This, I got from the Code of Conduct: "This Code of Conduct helps us build a community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect."

I asked support if this code (the spirit of the code, as stated here) does not apply to those who downvote and report. The people who do that, don't undo what they do, when a revision is made trying to improve the post. I was waiting to see how my revised question would be dealt with. Vega, Sweeper, marc_s deleted the question 9 hours ago. If you're reading this, I would like to hear your rationale behind the decision to delete. I promise I won't harass you no matter what you have to say. I would just like to know, so I can improve my behavior on SO, for the future. So I can adjust and adapt to the community, even if I believe the community is toxic.

I sincerely hope the people who actually answer the questions and the people who downvote and report and delete are not the same. I like to think that some people at least, are here because they actually want to try and help others like me.

Comment: Personally I don't see any reason to delete that question, but I think it's a bit over the top to assume the people who voted to do so did it to "squash a noob". In the spirit of the CoC it's also nice to assume good intentions even if you disagree with people's actions.

Comment: One thing that takes a bit of time to learn is how to provide debugging details. Just saying some code *"doesn't work"* is virtually meaningless without mention of errors thrown, what part does work vs what part doesn't and what steps you have used to try to troubleshoot. The fact the code was obfuscated is probably what set off the down voting. If you had posted the formatted original source version it would have helped along with the debugging details you would have had a better chance of success

Comment: "In the spirit of the CoC...": Were you suggesting I should assume their good intentions? Doesn't the reverse apply to me? Shouldn't they have assumed my good intentions, and tried to give me and my question the benefit of the doubt? Like I said, does the CoC apply to me or does it or does it not apply to them?

Comment: @MehBMe The action of downvoting/closing/deleting posts is not inherently malicious. So, those who took that action didn't need to _assume_ anything. They voted based on (how they judge) the quality of the question.

Comment: @MehBMe When users vote a post, the intentions of the author are irrelevant. Of course the voters can "assumer your intentions were good", and yet find the post not useful.

Comment: So, please give me some guidance on how I may further improve the original question, and get it reopened. I don't think it's a useless question.

Comment: The other main issue is it is not absolutely clear what you expect the code to do. There is mention of *"complex urls"* in title but then only vague discussion about *"the original link"* and neither of those concepts gets detailed or linked together. A more concise explanation of exactly what you expect the code to do would also help

Comment: On top of that, as stated your question expects a "yes/no" answer, and apparently you already know that the answer is "no" for Firefox. Maybe you should redefine the question to "how to accomplish X".

Comment: @MehBMe As a first step, please edit the question and post the original code and make sure it's well-formatted as suggested by charlietfl above. The question may get reopened and undeleted if it's improved.

Comment: So...from reviewers perspective nobody could read the code, nobody know exactly what it is for and no specific errors mentioned. Far too many unknowns for anyone to even be able to guess at advice. Other users did what is expected for such a scenario, vote to close

Comment: @41686d6564, I'll try... I'm a bit hampered by the fact that I wrote this code some time back, and IIRC, this snippet (the encoded version) was generated using another script I wrote. But since I've had a disk failure and lost some data. Not sure if the original code is available anymore.

Comment: If that's the case, how would you fix it even if you knew what causes the issue?

Comment: @charlietfl, I think I already explained that this code is supposed to redirect to a mailto: url, and that this wasn't happening, and the link was opening in a new tab, but not being navigated to... So what I expect the code to do is just redirect to a mailto: address. The original link was linked to in the initial version of the post, but I later included it inline within the post. It's the encoded javascript: url.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not even understand what do you mean by "redirect to mailto:". There is no such a thing. Maybe you need to edit your question to better explain that as well?

Comment: @charlietfl, To fix, I would be trying to alter the 1st level decoding I provided.

Comment: @MehBMe If you believe someone else is in breach of the CoC that's really not a good argument for not following it yourself. The question was at a -5 score, people might very well vote to delete it to save you from even more downvotes. They might also have believed it is not possible to edit it into shape. There are several explanations that are more likely than that they did it out of spite.

Comment: Somewhat explained it but vague terms like *"but the link isn't parsed and handled"* are not absolutely clear and definitive. I have no real idea what that means and can't read the code either to understand more

Comment: @charlietfl, I was trying to explain that the behavior exhibited by Edge is the expected one, and the behavior exhibited by the latest Firefox versions is not expected. "but the link isn't parsed and handled" means the link is not being navigated to in new Firefox.

Comment: @yivi, I meant redirected to an address of the form described in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto. I used the word redirect, because I was setting window.location to a new url, effectively a redirect.

Comment: Ok... what is source for the link? What is it's value? What troubleshooting have you tried? Errors? etc. Try to de-minify more the level 1 code so it can be put into formatted lines also. With all this advice and looking through a bunch of other questions on the site you should be able to now put together a far better structured and unambiguous question

Comment: That's not a redirect, MehBMe. A redirect is generally a `30*` header. At worst, a `refresh` html meta header. You cannot "redirect" to a mailto: address, because it implies a change of protocol and client. That's not a redirect.

Comment: @yivi, Do you know the correct term for what I'm trying to explain, if not redirect?

Comment: Not really, I don't fully understand what you want to do. I'm just telling you this because if you do not ask the correct question, you won't get a good answer. Usually asking the right question takes you halfway to the answer.

Comment: A `mailto:` link should simply open a new email in users default mail program and use the query string to fill in various parts of it

Comment: @charlietfl, That's what I'm trying to achieve. To open a new email in user's default mail program.  If someone just tried the link in Edge, or Firefox 70.0, they would have seen this for themselves. Can you help me better phrase my question?

Comment: I would never run code I can't fully read...most others wouldn't either. It's not even clear how you are using that code

Comment: `mailto:` is a protocol, just like `http:` or `https:`. It's an instruction to the browser telling it what to do with the URL. For the HTTP protocol it will open a webpage, for mailto it will typically refer to the OS and usually cause the default mail application to be opened. I'm guessing someone aiming to answer that question would already know this though, even if you refer to it as a redirect. Including a code snippet in the question would make it a lot easier for people to actually see the problem. As it stands "just trying the link" in Edge/Firefox is a bit of effort.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to improve my question further, but it seems edits are no longer being allowed, because the question has been deleted.

Comment: That's wierd, you should be able to edit a deleted question. I know I can.

Comment: @MehBMe Deleted posts can still be edited, and then flagged for undeletion.

Comment: I'm not going to run some encoded javascript that you refuse to reveal the full source code of nor the way it was encoded. You expect me to trust you and your code while we hardly met. I advice to create a new minimal reproducible example with full code, include how to encode it that reproduces the problem on your end and then we might have a question that is worth keeping around. At the moment it could as well be an awesome hack.

Comment: I just edited that question. If I can, so can you.

Comment: @rene, I'll try. I thought I wasn't allowed to edit because I received this: "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" while I was still typing into the question body. Maybe it's a glitch with the autosave.

Comment: Is the current edit any better? Should I undelete?

Comment: What I cannot understand is why all these 'toxic' users are still bothering to try and help you at all.  How/why did you jump from 'my question was downvoted and closed' to 'the community is toxic'?

Comment: @MartinJames it shows your age, sorry. Calling someone or a group "toxic" is the modern way of saying "Hello, nice to see you, how is your day?". Whether you return the greeting is up to you.

Comment: @MartinJames Sorry, I didn't mean to offend any of the genuinely helpful users. But I have been downvoted before for reasons I did not understand. I believe in open dialogue, conversation. I believe that can go far...

Comment: My thanks to everyone who showed up and expressed their help, suggestions, advice, feedback. I appreciate your contribution towards making this community better.

Comment: Also, @MartinJames, to clarify, when I said toxic, I was referring to things like how some users keep downvoting even this question. Not sure if they dislike my question or how the discussion is progressing. gnat's meta effect reference made me empathize even if I don't understand the reason behind said effect very well.

Comment: @MehBMe is it possible ppl downvote cause they are tired of being labeled toxic for the wrong reasons? As soon as a new user doesn't like ANYTHING that happens on the site, they get demeaning, rude and insulting. You can sympathize with the meta effect. Can you sympathize with ppl like Rene, ivarni, Charlie, who help *despite* the toxic label, and will still be labeled toxic by at least half a dozen rants before this week is ended?

Comment: @Patrice, when I referred to "squash the noob", I meant the way people seem to be prejudiced against new users. Why assume new users are all bad? "As soon as a new user doesn't like ANYTHING that happens on the site, they get demeaning, rude and insulting": Do you put all new users in that category? What happened to benefit of the doubt? And, yes, I can sympathize with people who get called toxic for no reason. I DO appreciate the efforts of the genuinely helpful people. But as a new user, did I deserve being downvoted? I wonder.

Comment: I have given the community an opportunity to prove that they are not toxic by their actions. Check the downvote count on my posts. Was I wrong to label the downvoters as toxic? Did I ever sound unfriendly at any point in the discussions? Yet, I was downvoted. You may decide if my opinions are validated.

Comment: FWIW, I'm part of the community too. All I can do is try hard not to be toxic myself. If this wasn't on record, would it have motivated others to try to be better? Maybe this will make a difference.

Comment: 'I have given the community an opportunity to prove that they are not toxic by their actions' what!!   Are you remotely serious?  You think that the burden of proof is for some group to prove that they are non-toxic?????   You expect that the skilled and experienced developers on SO would fall for that tactic?   You should stop those irrational and unproven allegations and insults as some may find them offensive.  I don't give a PHP about what you have to say anymore.

Comment: @MehBMe I mean... Didn't you come here and labelled everyone toxic at first chance? I just call what I see. Routinely, new users come to meta and lash out at everyone. Yes, we can be better. But it won't be by you assuming ppl are out there 'to get you'. I'm sorry.... 'I call you toxic and if you downvote me for it, **well you prove my point**. It's like saying 'youre argumentative'. I either say 'yes I am' or 'no I'm not'. Both points have me look like argumentative. 'youre all toxic' : upvotes = ppl agree. Downvotes = ppl are toxic. I see no win.

Comment: @Patrice, I didn't mean that as a blanket accusation. As in everybody, though in hindsight, I can see that some may have seen it that way. Like I mentioned before, I was referring to the downvoters, specifically. I didn't make that statement in my previous question, yet that too was downvoted. I just thought, maybe I was wrong, that there was a prejudice against new users in particular.

Comment: I can see that maybe I'm not communicating my thoughts very well. I don't wish to offend anyone any further. I won't post any more comments here except possibly in response to further comments.

Comment: Well thanks for providing this week's meta post about toxicity though. They're always good to keep the blood pumping. Have you at least changed your mind about the dedicated site feature which is the downvote button, a button which is designed to in no way encourage people to explain why they hit it just like the upvote button in no way encourages people to explain why they hit it? It's all part of the design of the site, we're all just people using it as instructed. Have mercy.

Comment: @Gimby, Oh well, so this has become a post about toxicity from the original intent of asking how to improve my original question. I don't think I have ever actually downvoted anyone on any site, ever, only upvoted on occasion. Guess that's just me.

Comment: @MehBMe "I don't think I have ever actually downvoted anyone on any site" - you actually *can't* downvote anyone, at least, not yet. Users need 125 rep to be able to downvote. Like most rep restrictions, it's a way to prevent trolling.

Comment: @F1Krazy, I said ANY site, not SO, not SE. I wonder if I have given everyone the wrong impression. I don't think unkindly of anyone, despite how they treat me. Of course, the downvotes are hurtful, but I can handle that. "There was no unkindness in Miss Marple, she just did not trust people. Though she expected the worst, she often accepted people kindly in spite of what they were". This seemed to resonate with me. There's more where that came from, but I think that should suffice. You'll be able to look up the rest if you wish.

Comment: Should I delete this question or let the community decide? The downvotes seem to indicate it's unpopular... Only, it's been answered already and I've accepted.

Comment: I voted to undelete. That was the deciding vote, but it said "21 more votes to undelete" (possibly paraphrased). What gives?

Comment: [Detailed privileges table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I think the original question has been undeleted, but still closed. I'm not sure if the community would like your voting for it to be undeleted. There seem to be some strong opinions about me or my posts, judging by the downvotes. I have tried to clarify some more points in an edit, but not sure if we should have let sleeping dragons lie.

Comment: Ok, so I have managed to reduce and simplify the question quite significantly. You don't get the fancy link, but with this we can probably avoid all this angst about dubious looking code. The new question narrows down the issue much more.

Comment: I have managed to reverse engineer a bookmarklet to generate a URL similar to what's on the site. Not sure where to post it or if anyone's actually interested, anymore.

Comment: I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What are you looking for if the question is undeleted and reopened?

You've created [an issue in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1667009). That bug explains that it's a Firefox issue and what you can do to work around it. I imagine the bug will get fixed at some point and that will be that.

Browser bugs are certainly better off being recorded on the browsers bug-tracking sites as that's where they will be investigated and fixed. The best Stack Overflow can do here is offer a workaround or point you to the bugtracker's bug.

Maybe this question and the answer that it's a Firefox bug would be of interest to some people while the bug exists so if the question was clear enough it could be undeleted and reopened, but its long term value is likely limited once the underlying browser bug is fixed.

If you really want the question reopened then making it clearer what's going on, using the Bugzilla analysis, would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping for a temporary workaround until the bug is fixed in Firefox, which may take time, if it's indeed a bug and not some security feature gone bad. If it was a feature and if they decided they're not going to fix it, I would still need a workaround, that's why I asked. Ok, so I won't reopen the question for now, but will monitor the Bugzilla for some time.

Comment: I see what you meant now, but I had added the target="_blank" attribute to the link so the original (home) page wouldn't get replaced. That's still a requirement. So removing the attribute isn't really a proper workaround. It still doesn't provide the desired outcome.

Comment: In that case there is no workaround for you. You'll just have to wait for the bug to be fixed, or fix it yourself like I do.

Comment: Should I delete the question? Is that OK with you?

Comment: I don't see why it needs to be deleted and you won't be able to if you try.

Comment: I only asked because the question seems to be unpopular, and yes, looks like I CAN delete it, but I'll wait for other opinions, Thanks.